# Jquery fullcalendar eventClick function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [**FullCalendar**](http://fullcalendar.io/) plugin for my calendar.

I am trying to loop through some ajax data I have acquired and populate my calendar with the relevant fields I want to use.

This is what i'm doing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $requests.length; i++)
{ 
  var currEvent = {
    title: $requests[i].staff_name,
    start: new Date($requests[i].start_date),
    end: new Date($requests[i].end_date),
    backgroundColor: $requests[i].color,
    borderColor: $requests[i].color,
    textColor: "white",
  }

  $module.fullCalendar(
    'renderEvent',
     currEvent,
     true
   );
 }
```

This will populate my calendar but i've been trying to add the `eventClick` callback so i can alert out the event's title or something. But everything I do results in either not outputting to the calendar or outputting with the click function doing nothing. How can I render my events and then assign a click function to each one?

Comment: Check the **[docs here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/)**

Comment: When I use the given code here, it doesn't render my events to the calendar. I need to render and assign click

Answer (score 0):

This code will do it, I was also accidentally calling the plugin twice which screwed it up completely.

```
$module.fullCalendar({
                weekends: false,
                eventLimit: 3,
                editable: false,
                disableResizing: false,
                events: allEvents,
                eventClick: function(event, element) {
                  alert(event.title);
                }
              });
```